# Extracting NDVI value

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I am just new to GIS and Python. I have a shapefile of a country and a file with 300 locations (latitude and longitude) from different parts of this country. I extract the NDVI (Landsat 8; band 3 and band 4) and ALAN (NOAA and DMSP) map by using the Google Earth Engine and now I want to extract the value of NDVI and ALAN for each location. I tried to do this by using the zonal statistics in QGIS app but couldn't. Can you suggest some simple material for training or explain how can I do this? The ones I found are a little complicated.

Comment: For your lon, lat points, use the [Sample raster values](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling) tool, not Zonal Statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this tutorial: [Sampling Raster Data using Points or Polygons](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/sampling_raster_data.html)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, it was great. now I have another question in terms of extracting NDVI value from QGIS. I know I should use Zonal statistics but when I want to calculate NDVI I don't have the band I need. I mean it doesn't appear in QGIS.

Comment: Please post a new question with the data you are using and what exactly the problems are. Adding images showing other users would be helpful as well.

Comment: BTW: don't you mean bands 4 and 5 for NDVI??